# Component does not display when clicking the navBar button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a NavBar component where I have some links.

I then call this component on my App.js, so I can display the NavBar.

When I click on a link I navigate to the route but the component is not displayed.

Here is my code:

**MainNavigation.js**

```
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";


function MainNavigation() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const MyApp = (
    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1"  button='/'>
        <RouterLink to='/' className={classes.logo}>MyApp</RouterLink>
    </Typography>
  );

  const headersData = [
    {
      label: "First",
      href: "/first",
    },
    {
     label: "Second",
     href: "/second"
    }
  ];

  const getMenuButtons = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          {...{
            key: label,
            color: "inherit",
            to: href,
            component: RouterLink,
            className: classes.menuButton,
          }}
        >
          {label}
        </Button>
      );
    });
  };

  const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
        {MyApp}
        <div>{getMenuButtons()}</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <AppBar className={classes.header}>{displayDesktop()}</AppBar>
    </header>
  );
}

export default MainNavigation;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Second from './pages/Second';
import First from './pages/First';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import MainNavigation from './components/layout/MainNavigation';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <MainNavigation/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/first" element={<First />} />
          <Route path="/second" element={<Second />} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Second.js**

```
function Second() {
    return <div>Second</div>;
}

export default Second
```

The Component is called when I click on a link because I console logged just to check.
I don't know what is happening, since I don't get any errors, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issues with your routing/navigation implementation, it's working just fine...

***BUT***

You should be aware that the `AppBar` component uses fixed positioning by default, so it actually overlays your content.

[AppBar props](https://v4.mui.com/api/app-bar/#props)

[image]

You can either use some other position value and make the app bar render with the content (*probably not what you want in an app header*), or you can app `margin-top` to your contents to push them down below the app bar header.

Example:

```
h1.header {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit zen-wilson-dgf6w]

Comment: I was thinking on that problem, but then I inspected the html and I didn't see my text so I thought it was not that, thank you for the answer.